# I did not bind my function's "this" in the constructor, but why isn't "this" undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My button has the following onClick function

```
<button
  onClick={() => this.onDismiss(item.objectID)}
  type="button"
>
```

I have an onDismiss function that filters a list and updates my react application. I did not bind the function's "this" to its constructor. I purposely commented the "this" binding out but the application still works. Does the ES6 arrow functions automatically bind the funciton's "this" to the class Component? Shouldn't I be getting undefined?

My codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/portfolio-0rzfo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: You're calling the function using `this.` so its context will be set to whatever `this` is in that context. [More details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function does not have its own `this`. The `this` value of the
>   enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal
>   variable lookup rules. So while searching for `this` which is not
>   present in current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the `this`
>   from its enclosing scope.

That is why you do not need to bind the Component's scope to the function.